# SQL Tree Leaf Nodes UPDATE

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I am trying to update a table that resembles a tree. I want to update a column to determine if each node is a leaf node.
The table looks like this:

```
#NodeTable:
NodeID | ParentID | IsLeaf
--------------------------
0      | NULL     | 0 
1      | 0        | 0
3      | 1        | 0
5      | 3        | 0
6      | 3        | 0
7      | 1        | 0
```

Im trying to update the table with the following command:

```
UPDATE #NodeTable
SET IsLeaf = 
    CASE
        WHEN NodeID IN (SELECT ParentID FROM #NodeTable) THEN 0 ELSE 1
    END
```

The logic is that if NodeID appears in (SELECT ParentID..) then it is not a leaf node therefore IsLeaf should be 0 otherwise if its not there, it is a leaf and IsLeaf should be a 1.

This statement however doesn't do what I thought it would. Any help would be appreciated.

The end result should look like this:

## NodeTable:

```
NodeID | ParentID | IsLeaf
--------------------------
0      | NULL     | 0 
1      | 0        | 0
3      | 1        | 0
5      | 3        | 1
6      | 3        | 1
7      | 1        | 1
```

Comment: im super new to databases and sql. could you ELI5?

Comment: @BigShiba are you using MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, Postgre?

Comment: @EzLo Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to tag the leaves, you can use `NOT EXISTS` against all parents.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#NodeTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #NodeTable

CREATE TABLE #NodeTable (
    NodeID INT,
    ParentID INT,
    IsLeaf BIT DEFAULT 0)

INSERT INTO #NodeTable (
    NodeID,
    ParentID)
VALUES
    (0, NULL),
    (1, 0),
    (3, 1),
    (5, 3),
    (6, 3),
    (7, 1)

UPDATE L SET
    IsLeaf = 1
FROM
    #NodeTable AS L
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'does not have any children' FROM #NodeTable AS P WHERE L.NodeID = P.ParentID)


SELECT * FROM #NodeTable AS T ORDER BY T.NodeID
```

Comment: @BigShiba I've tested it with your examples and it marked as leaves the rows 5, 6 and 7. Post your desired outcome on your question.

Comment: ive edited the OP and your results are correct. I dont understand why its not doing anything for me. Can I see your code?

Comment: Our set ups are almost identical. I have no idea why its not updating anything...

Comment: @BigShiba are your working with a physical table that might have a trigger linked to it? Or maybe using a transaction that is not being commited, or it's being rolled back?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS`  :

```
UPDATE n 
     SET n.IsLeaf = (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #NodeTable WHERE ParentID = n.NodeID) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
FROM #NodeTable n;
```

Comment: hm. This makes all the rows a 1 under IsLeaf

Comment: @BigShiba. . . I can't believe with your comment.